# Can't ping using yocto

Tags: linux, ip, ping, yocto

[image]I've built and installed yocto (5.4.44-05635-gb810a419a2fa-dirty) on my Arria 10 board. I checked for an IP assignment:

```
$ ip address

eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 1a:34:f8:09:da:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.150.113/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1834:f8ff:fe09:da11/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I then tried pinging 169.254.150.117 which is the static IP address for the laptop connected to the board. Using WireShark I can see the broadcast ARP message coming from the board requesting: "Who has 169.254.150.117? Tell 169.254.150.113". I can also see that the laptop is sending response: "169.254.150.117 is at ". But it appears that the board isn't receiving incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

In arch/arm/boot/dts/socfpga_arria10_socdk.dtsi change:

```
&gmac0 {
phy-mode = "rgmii";
phy-addr = <0xffffffff>; /* probe for phy addr */

/*
 * These skews assume the user's FPGA design is adding 600ps of delay
 * for TX_CLK on Arria 10.
 *
 * All skews are offset since hardware skew values for the ksz9031
 * range from a negative skew to a positive skew.
 * See the micrel-ksz90x1.txt Documentation file for details.
 */
txd0-skew-ps = <0>; /* -420ps */
txd1-skew-ps = <0>; /* -420ps */
txd2-skew-ps = <0>; /* -420ps */
txd3-skew-ps = <0>; /* -420ps */
rxd0-skew-ps = <420>; /* 0ps */
rxd1-skew-ps = <420>; /* 0ps */
rxd2-skew-ps = <420>; /* 0ps */
rxd3-skew-ps = <420>; /* 0ps */
txen-skew-ps = <0>; /* -420ps */
txc-skew-ps = <1860>; /* 960ps */
rxdv-skew-ps = <420>; /* 0ps */
rxc-skew-ps = <1680>; /* 780ps */
max-frame-size = <3800>;
status = "okay";
```

};

To:

```
&gmac0 {
phy-mode = "rgmii-id";
phy-addr = <0xffffffff>; /* probe for phy addr */
status = "okay";
```

};

The problem was the PHY chip on the Altera/Intel Arria 10 ref board uses a Micrel chip and the PHY chip on our design board is a Marvel chip.